# py appended to filename when saving files

Tags: firefox

I have firefox upgraded to 9 and then 10.  Q installed on ubuntu lucid.

Now when I save an `htm` file it gets saved as `xx.htm.py`.  When an image is saved it is saved as `xxx.jpg.py`. Same thing happens for `pdf` files as well.

Why does this occur? Is this a bug in FireFox?  The problem happened since I upgraded to FireFox 9 from previous version.

Comment: Does this happen on any site, also e.g. on Super User? Or is it only a specific site that has `.py` URLs?

Comment: if I try File->save Page As for this (superuser site) page, it shows as py-appended-to-filename-when-saving-files.py  .However,if I try save Link As on let's say the ASkQuestion link above, it shows as ask.htm .

Comment: This is happening with me as well on a Linux machine. On a Windows machine it appends `.rb` extension. Am using Firefox 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had filed a bug against this on the Mozilla site, and got it resolved:
[Bug 728690 - Adds .py extension while saving files](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728690)

The problem was caused by the `Selenium IDE: Python Formatters` extension. Things worked fine on disabling it.

Disable all "Selenium IDE: XXX Formatters" extensions if you have more than one.